# Sharepoint Search REST API - 401 unauthorized Error (Need Help)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am getting 401 unauthorized error when calling a sharepoint search rest api (http://:/_api/search/query?querytext=) from a .net application using claims based authentication.

My request and error as below

```
private void GetSearchResponse(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
{
    try
    {
        using (var httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (var stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                ProcessSearchResponse(stream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {//catch and log the error
    }
```

> stack trace : "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-2147024891, 
>           System.UnauthorizedAccessException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"Access
>   denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access 
>       this resource.\"}}}"

Thanks a lot in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

Since SharePoint Online/Office 365 relies on Claims authentication use:

- [SharePointOnlineCredentials class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) to provide credentials to
  access SharePoint Online resources.
- specify `X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED` HTTP header

The following example demonstrates how to consume SharePoint Search REST using `HttpWebRequest` class:

```
public static SharePointOnlineCredentials PrepareSPOCredentials(string userName, string passWord)
{
    var securePassWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in passWord.ToCharArray()) securePassWord.AppendChar(c);
    var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassWord);
    return credentials;
}

public static string ExecuteSearchRequest(Uri address,ICredentials credentials,string query)
{
   string result;
   var endpointUrl = new Uri(address,string.Format("/_api/search/query?querytext='{0}'",query));

   var request = WebRequest.Create(endpointUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
   request.Credentials = credentials;
   request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
   request.Method = "GET";
   request.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose";
   var response = request.GetResponse();
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
   {
       result = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
   return result;
}


//Usage
var credentials = PrepareSPOCredentials(userName, password);
var result = ExecuteSearchRequest(webUri, credentials, "contentclass:STS_ListItem AND ContentType:Task");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are using HTTP Post. And i tried all your parameters in request but getting the same 401 unauthorized error. Is it something we need to give access at centeral admin or AD level? because the same piece of code is working fine production but it is not working in dev.

Comment: I am also getting [MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.

Answer (score 0):

The Search results have results which the particular user does not have access to . That is why you receive forbidden error .

While using the REST API provides a much more succinct way to retrieve data, there are apparently areas where you’ll need to use the more robust CSOM.

Comment: How and where can i add the permission to the particular user? Thanks for your help in advance. I am struggling a lot on this :(

Comment: http://sharepointbrandon.com/2013/08/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-retrieving-subsites-and-getting-forbidden-error-fixed-with-csom/ . . Please add the code as well to your question .

Comment: i may not change my code since the code is working fine in production.

Comment: @Nikil, Please refer my question for the updated code.

Comment: is your site anonymous and also using workflows ?

Comment: nope. we are not using any workflow

Answer (score 0):

I have been using below. Worked for me for 10 days. Not sure what happened after that.
The user account is still a SCA on the site and the password is still valid.

```
var securePassword = new SecureString();
                    foreach (var c in GlobalVar.siteSCAPassword)
                    {
                        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                    }
                    credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(GlobalVar.siteSCAUserName, securePassword);

using (var client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
                        client.Credentials = credentials;
                        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/atom+xml;type=entry");
                        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/atom+xml");

                        #region TOTAL PAGES
                        WriteLog("===TOTAL PAGES");
                        var uriTP = new Uri(GlobalVar.siteUrl + GlobalVar.searchApiSuffix + @"'*'&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=10000&selectproperties='Title'&sourceid='fba6c3ac-3b5f-4714-9e27-87637da9e5fd'");
                        uriTP = new Uri(GlobalVar.siteUrl + GlobalVar.searchApiSuffix + @"'*'&trimduplicates=true&rowlimit=10&selectproperties='Title'");
                        WriteLog("Rest API : " + uriTP.AbsoluteUri);
                        var resultTP = client.DownloadString(uriTP);
}
```

The bottom line var resultTP = client.DownloadString(uriTP); now starts throwing 401 (unauthorized) error.